# HDMI Output To 4k TV: Resolution Too Low And No Audio

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, hdmi, lenovo-laptop

I recently acquired a Lenovo Thinkpad x260, running Windows 10 Pro. When I try and connect it via the HDMI port to a JVC 4K TV, I have the following issues:

- The TV is detected as an extra monitor but the maximum (recommended) resolution is limited to 1920x1080, although the TV and the x260 are both capable of running at 3840x2160.
- I can't get the HDMI to play any audio. When I check the "Playback Devices" in the sound control panel all I see is the soundcard for the laptop (Realtek).

I know this is *not* a hardware issue, because when I run Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) on the same machine then the TV is detected (as "Vestel Elktronik Sanayi ve Ticaret A. S. 85"), I can set the resolution to 3840x2160, and the sound works perfectly.

Things that I have already tried:

- Running Windows update and upgraded all drivers (including optional ones)
- Running the Lenovo update utility and upgrading all drivers
- Making sure that the sound control panel displays any "disabled devices" (in case the HDMI audio was disabled for some reason)
- Tried upgrading the drivers from Lenovo's site directly
- Resetting Windows

The weird thing is, when I first got the laptop and briefly checked that the HDMI was working OK, I'm pretty sure that the resolution and sound worked without problem. However, now they do not (I'm assuming after a few Windows updates etc.). I'm assuming that it must be some kind of driver issue, but I've run out of things to try.

What could be the problem, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: You may want to check the Windows Device Manager and see if there are any devices that have driver issues.

Comment: @Blaelph Thanks, but the Device Manager is clean - no reported problems.

Comment: Hmm, makes me wonder if Windows update installed a generic driver over a device specific one.  Perhaps manually install ["Audio" and "Display and Video Graphics" drivers from Lenovo's website](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x260/downloads/driver-list/), reboot and see if it works then?

Comment: I already tried downloading the driver from Lenovo's website, but still no joy.